# Keys not being passed on svn up when running gnu-screen

Tags: svn, putty, gnu-screen, pageant

I am SSHing into a server using putty I have set-up putty with pageant to allow key forwarding.

this set-up works absolutely fine and when I run 'svn up' the update runs fine.

but if I start running gnu-screen 'screen -DR' when I run 'svn up' it starts asking for my password for the svn server.

Has anyone else had this problem? 
Any ideas where the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ~/.subversion/config file, under [tunnels], add

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -l (your username) -i (path to your key)
```

e.g., I have

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -l cjbrown -i /home/cjbrown/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Comment: That worked thanks. Would be interested to find out why screen stops the key forwarding working if any one knows.